# Converting a SQL Query to a Predicate Expression using Fluent Synatx

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

How do I write the following sql query to a Predicate Expression using Fluent Sytax:

```
select c.* from customer c
inner join Orders r on r.CustomerId = c.Id
where
    c.MemberSince > '01/01/2013' &&
    r.OrderDate > '01/01/2014'
order by r.OrderDate
```

I am expecting something like this:

```
Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> filters = PredicateBuilder.True<Customer>();
filters = filters.And(x => x.MemberSince > DateTime.Parse('01/01/2013'));
filterr = ....
```

I am not sure how to add the Orders predicate. And then I call:

```
var list = db.Customers.AsExpandable().Where(filters).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need PredicateBuilder at all. You just need to understand that the result of a join is effectively a sequence of pairs:

```
DateTime memberCutoff = ...;
DateTime orderCutoff = ...;
var query = context.Customers
                   .Join(context.Orders,
                         c => c.Id, r => r.CustomerId, (c, r) => new { c, r })
                   .Where(pair => pair.c.MemberSince > memberCutoff &&
                                  pair.r.OrderDate > orderCutoff)
                   .OrderBy(pair => pair.r.OrderDate);
```

Comment: ok. Perfect. If I wanted to do this using a predicateBuilder, how is that possible?

Comment: @user3237706: That's slightly tricky due to the anonymous class. You may be able to a `Tuple<,>` instead of the anonymous class, and then use `PredicateBuilder` with an `Expression<Func<Tuple<Customer, Order>, bool>`. I'm not sure whether LINQ to SQL recognizes Tuple.